# How to build Price Comparison with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have to build a price comparison system. My idea was to use Elasticsearch to build on. 
Now I have this problem. How can I aggregate seller prices for each Product.

As Example see this Screenshot: 
[image]

Let me say I have this simple mapping:

```
products: {
    product: {
        properties: {
            id: {
                type: "long"
            },
            name: {
                type: "string"
            },
            ....
            sellers: {
                dynamic: "true",
                properties: {
                    sellerId: {
                        type: "long"
                    },
                    price: {
                        type: "float"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I aggregate or facet the price (min,max, and sellers count) for each Product?

Or is there a way to build this thing with parent child relations?

Comment: Do you really want to represent price as a `float` (or `double` for that matter)? Chances are, you do not because of rounding issues.

Comment: Hi @pickypg what type do you recommend?

Comment: @richardwhatever Until [BigDecimal support](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/5491) arrives, then I would use a `long` with the money value multiplied by 100 to remove decimal places (e.g., $1.23 becomes 123). That should work unless you need more than two digits of precision. If you require more than two decimal points, then it's going to lose precision (and therefore be inaccurate) as a `double` (and even worse as a `float`) because of the nature of floating point numbers.

Comment: @pickypg I'm just storing and comparing normal 2 decimal place prices in Elasticsearch. All discounts and calculations are done prior to adding to search index. In this situation would a float not manage to reliably store 2 decimal places of accuracy? I just don't want to over optimise/complicate where its not necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using 1.0 and not 0.90, then you can do this quite easily using [min](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html), [max](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) and [value_count](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) aggregations.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "item1"
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "Min": {
      "min": {
        "field": "sellers.price"
      }
    },
    "Max": {
      "max": {
        "field": "sellers.price"
      }
    },
    "SellerCount": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "sellers.sellerId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, you could use a sub-aggregation to return the information for each product and not a specific one.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "Products": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Min": {
          "min": {
            "field": "sellers.price"
          }
        },
        "Max": {
          "max": {
            "field": "sellers.price"
          }
        },
        "SellerCount": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "sellers.sellerId"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```